# How can I include my resource files in my framework without using a separate bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been following this guide to create an iOS static library: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#walkthrough. I managed to create a framework that can be imported into another Xcode project.

Now, I want my framework to be able to show a Storyboard. I imagine that the `.storyboard` file counts as a resource. The previous guide states that I should create a Bundle for my resource files, such as images, instead of putting them in the framework itself.

However, I **do** want to put them in the framework itself. I don't want to use a separate bundle.

All guides I find around tell me the same thing. I understand the advantages of using a separate bundle, but I just don't want to do it right now.

Now then, I am lost on how to include my `.storyboard` file in my framework so that I can show it with this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NameOfStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NameOfViewController"];
[otherView presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The above code does not seem to work (it can't find the storyboard file). I imagine this is because the `.storyboard` is not currently included in the framework. Sadly, I don't know how to include it.

In the framework's Xcode project, under Build Phases, I see a tab labeled "Copy files" which looks like what I need.

[image]

Now, I'm not sure what this is doing, but in any case, it doesn't seem to be working anyway.

I also did this:

[image]

How can I include my `.storyboard` file in my framework without using a separate bundle?

Comment: Have you tried to create directly a framework ? maybe when you posted question, this target was not yet available. Your code works using a framework

Comment: have you get a solution of this?

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you want to use separate bundle for a framework? So if an app is using your framework it would be able to use resources from it(Xibs, storyboards, whatever)

For example a call from the app that uses your framework can look something like this:

```
FrameworkViewController *frameworkView = [[FrameworkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrameworkViewController"
                                                                          bundle:[NSBundle yourFrameworkBundle]];
```

and in your framework you can write a helper class NSBundle+YourFrameworkBundle that gives access to framework bundle:

NSBundle+YourFrameworkBundle.h

```
@interface NSBundle (YourFrameworkBundle)

+ (NSBundle *)yourFrameworkBundle;

@end
```

NSBundle+YourFrameworkBundle.m

```
#import "NSBundle+YourFrameworkBundle.h"

@implementation NSBundle (YourFrameworkBundle)

+ (NSBundle *)yourFrameworkBundle
{
static NSBundle *frameworkBundle = nil;
static dispatch_once_t predicate;

dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
    NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFrameworkBundle.bundle"]];
});

return frameworkBundle;
}

@end
```

To bundle Resources for the framework create a separate target where you would link all your resources.
[image]

Comment: Your solution is already documented in the tutorial I posted, and in every other tutorial out there. And yes, it works, but that is not the point of this question. I literally just want to know how to bundle resources in the framework.

Comment: Try to link them in a resources target under Copy Bundle Resources. Screenshot attached.